# Keyboard is not resigning when tapping uipickerview

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uipickerview, uikeyboard

I have two `UIPickerView` and one `UITextField` in my search view. Everything was working fine when I Input/Select the two `UIPickerView` first and then I input `UITextField`.

But when I change the order like Inputting `UITextField` then selecting `UIPickerView`, the problem happening is keyboard is not resigned when I tap on the `UIPickerView`s.

Below is my code

```
- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing: (UITextField *) textField
//---------------------------------------------------------------
{
    if (textField == self.txtFieldPoetName) {
        NSLog(@"sdsdfsd");
      [textField resignFirstResponder];
      if ( [self.poetNameArray count] > 0 ){
          [self showPoetNamePicker];
      }

    }
    else if (textField == self.txtFieldPoemType) {
        NSLog(@"jdjdjdjd");
        [textField resignFirstResponder];

        if( [self.poemTypeArray count] > 0 ){
            [self showPoemTypePicker];
        }
    }
}


- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    [textField resignFirstResponder];

}

- (void)showPoetNamePicker {

    [self resignKeyboard];

    startXMLParser_ = NO;

    self.actionSheet = [[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil]autorelease];
    self.actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
    self.actionSheet.title = @"Poet Name";
    self.poetNamePicker = [[[UIPickerView alloc] init]autorelease];
    self.poetNamePicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    self.poetNamePicker.dataSource = self;
    self.poetNamePicker.delegate = self;
    PickerType = 1;

    //Set up the display frame
    self.poetNamePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 35, 320, 120);

    //Add the picker to the view
    [self.actionSheet addSubview:self.poetNamePicker];

    UISegmentedControl *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Done"]];
    closeButton.momentary = YES; 
    closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 6.0f, 50.0f, 27.0f);
    closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(hidePicker:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.actionSheet addSubview:closeButton];
    [closeButton release];

    [self.actionSheet showInView:self.appDelegate.tabBarController.view];
    [self.actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 385)];
}

- (void)showPoemTypePicker {

    [self resignKeyboard];

    startXMLParser_ = YES;

    self.actionSheet = [[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil]autorelease];
    self.actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
    self.actionSheet.title = @"Poem Type";
    self.poemTypePicker = [[[UIPickerView alloc] init]autorelease];
    self.poemTypePicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    self.poemTypePicker.dataSource = self;
    self.poemTypePicker.delegate = self;
    PickerType = 2;

    //Set up the display frame
    self.poemTypePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 35, 320, 120);

    //Add the picker to the view
    [self.actionSheet addSubview:self.poemTypePicker];

    UISegmentedControl *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Done"]];
    closeButton.momentary = YES; 
    closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 6.0f, 50.0f, 27.0f);
    closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(hidePicker:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.actionSheet addSubview:closeButton];
    [closeButton release];

    [self.actionSheet showInView:self.appDelegate.tabBarController.view];
    [self.actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 385)];
}

- (void)hidePicker:(id)sender
{

  if( PickerType == 1 )
  {
    if ( [self.poetNameArray count] > 0 &&
    [self.txtFieldPoetName.text length] == 0 )
    {
        //self.poemTypeId = @"";
      self.txtFieldPoetName.text = [self.poetNameArray objectAtIndex:0];
      self.poetTypeId = [self.poetTypeIdArray objectAtIndex:0];
    }
  }
  else if( PickerType == 2 )
  {
    if ( [self.poemTypeArray count] > 0  &&
    [self.txtFieldPoemType.text length] == 0)
    {
        //self.poetTypeId = @"";
      self.txtFieldPoemType.text = [self.poemTypeArray objectAtIndex:0];
      self.poemTypeId = [self.poemTypeIdArray objectAtIndex:0];

    }
  }

  [self resignFirstResponder];
  self.actionSheet.hidden = YES;
  [self.actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:YES];

  if (startXMLParser_)
  {
    [self performSelector:@selector(startXMLParsing) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
  }
}

-(void)resignKeyboard{

    [self.txtFieldPoetName resignFirstResponder];
    [self.txtFieldPoemName resignFirstResponder];
    [self.txtFieldPoemType resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Comment: you are saying that you have one textField but there is looking 3 textField txtFieldPoetName, txtFieldPoemName, txtFieldPoemType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT :**

```
- (void) textFieldShouldBeginEditing: (UITextField *) textField
{
   if (textField == self.txtFieldPoetName)
   {
      if( [self.poemNameArray count] > 0 ){
       [self showPoetNamePicker];
      }
      return NO;
   }
   else if (textField == self.txtFieldPoemType)
   {
     if( [self.poemTypeArray count] > 0 ){
        [self showPoemTypePicker];
     }
     return NO;
   }
   else
   {
     return YES;
   }
}
```

---

In showPoetNamePicker add this:

```
 - (void)showPoetNamePicker
 {
     [self.view endEditing:YES];
     ........
     ........
 }
```

Comment: solved as i made mistake it should be textFieldShouldBeginEditing

Comment: when tapping on textfiled it shows the keyboard but when tapping on uipickerview it is not showing the picker

Comment: Both the uipickers and the textfield has to  work.my problem is when tapping the uitextfield ( which is not a uipicker) the keyboard comes.this is fine.when tap the above uitextfiled which is a uipicker the keyboard is not hidden and the pickerview is getting displayed by overlapping the keyboard.this is the issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you linked to delegate properly?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this method,

```
 -(void)resignKeyboard{

     [self.view endEditing:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I think it should be mentioned ... I think the better solution is to use inputView (and optionally inputAccessoryView) of each textField. Something like that:

```
-(void)setupTextFields{
  UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
  toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(endEditing)], nil];

  self.txtFieldPoetName.inputView = self.poetNamePicker;
  self.txtFieldPoetName.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
  self.txtFieldPoemType.inputView = self.poetTypePicker;
  self.txtFieldPoemType.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
}

-(void)endEditing{
  [self.txtFieldPoetName resignFirstResponder];
  [self.txtFieldPoemType resignFirstResponder];
}
```

OS ensures switching picker for keyboard and vice versa (it's displayed in same view as keyboard I guess).